# How to perform Tying the Knot/define observable recursively using iteself in Rx.Net?

Tags: rxjs, frp, rx.net, sodium, tying-the-knot

Sometimes the business logic seems to be able to naturally modeled by some recursive defined observables. Here is one example:

```cs
interface Demo {
    IObservable<CommandId> userCommands;
    IObservable<IObservable<IProcessingState>> processes;
    IObservable<CommandId> skippedCommands;
    IObservable<(CommandId, CommandResult)> RunCommand(CommandId id);
}

interface IProcessingState {
    bool IsProcessing {get;}
    CommandId? ProcessingId {get;}
}
```

For each command user inputs, it should either trigger a running process in prcocess, or emit one value in skippedCommands. Some direct translate of this logic maybe

```
var validCommands = userCommands.WithLatestFrom(processes).Where(x => !x.Item2.IsProcessing)
var skippedCommands = userCommands.WithLatestFrom(processes).Where(x => x.Item2.IsProcessing)
var processes = validCommands.Select(c => RunCommand(c))
```

As code above indicated, assign of `validCommands` and `processes` are mutual recursive, we can equivalently define `processes` directly using itself recursively by

```
var processes = userCommands.WithLatestFrom(processes)
                            .Where(x => !x.Item2.IsProcessing)
                            .Select(c => RunCommand(c))
```

However we can not define `prcesses` Observable in C# like this.

I've found several possible related things:

1. `Observable.Generate` constructor. However it seems that it is folding on its own state in a synchronize way, I don't know how to use `userCommands` observable and `RunCommand` in `Observable.Generate`;
2. Some operator like `exhaust` or `exhaustMap` in RxJS, while Rx.Net didn't provide this operator, there are serval 3rd-party libraries provided these operators, like [FSharp.Control.Reactive](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Control.Reactive/reference/fsharp-control-reactive-observablemodule.html).
   The implementation is something like

```
let exhaustMap f source =
        Observable.Create (fun (o : IObserver<_>) -> 
            let mutable hasSubscription = false
            let mutable innerSub = None
            let onInnerCompleted () =
                hasSubscription <- false
                innerSub |> Option.iter Disposable.dispose
            let onOuterNext x =
                if not hasSubscription then
                    hasSubscription <- true 
                    f x |> subscribeSafeWithCallbacks 
                            o.OnNext o.OnError onInnerCompleted
                        |> fun y -> innerSub <- Some y
            source
            |> subscribeSafeWithCallbacks
                onOuterNext o.OnError o.OnCompleted)
```

However, there are two problems.
a. directly use this operator does not fit requirements above, skipped commands will be silently ignored. We can modify source code a litter to fit the requirements, but there is still another problem
b. the implementation introduced two local mutable variables, and two nested subscription. I don't know if this is ok in all cases (will there be risk of data racing?), and prefer solutions based on composition of operators other than mutable references

3. [SodiumFRP](https://github.com/SodiumFRP/sodium) provided forward references types `StreamLoop` and `CellLoop`. And by the Functional Reactive Programming book, Rx alternative for these forward references types would be `Subject`, by using `Subject` the recursive construct above is separated into two phases. The problem is by Intro to Rx indicated, using `Subject` requires manually manage more state, at least dispose of the subject is required, and maybe forced to hot observables. I'm wondering if there exists solutions without using `Subject`
4. Using `window` operator with boundary on last value (just before finish) on `RunCommand` results, the `processes` above can some how be constructed, but this solution need to use ending signal twice, which requires careful treatment (quiet a while on trying and tuning `Take(1)`, `zip`, `withLatestFrom`, `combineLatest`, overloads of `Window` operators to get desired result) on simultaneous events.

Are there better solutions or modification to solutions above to this problem, especially only use operators?

Answer (score 0):

Your types are all weird and hard to work with. Your question is fundamentally a simple state machine with two triggers: 1) New command arrives, 2) Previous command finishes executing.

This should get you started:

```
void Main()
{
    IObservable<ICommand> source = new Subject<ICommand>();
    var executionTerminatedLoopback = new Subject<Unit>();
    
    var stateMachine = source
        .Select(c => (command: c, type: 1))
        .Merge(executionTerminatedLoopback.Select(_ => (command: (ICommand)null, type: 2)))
        .Scan((isExecuting: false, validCommand: (ICommand)null, failedCommand: (ICommand)null), (state, msg) => {
            if(msg.type == 2)
                return (false, null, null);
            if(state.isExecuting)
                return (true, null, msg.command);
            else
                return (true, msg.command, null);
        });
    
    var validCommands = stateMachine.Where(t => t.validCommand != null).Select(t => t.validCommand);
    var failedCommands = stateMachine.Where(t => t.failedCommand != null).Select(t => t.failedCommand);
    
    validCommands.SelectMany(c => c.Execute()).Subscribe(executionTerminatedLoopback);
}

public interface ICommand{ 
    IObservable<Unit> Execute();
}
```

`source` here doesn't have to be a subject, and probably shouldn't be: It can be any `IObservable<ICommand>`. It's just easier to mock up in an answer. The `exeuctionTerminatedLoopback` though does have to be, to (as you put it) break up the recursion into two parts. Because it's a subject, it should be kept private and not leaked out.

I don't think there are any answers in C# without using Subject.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although not directly related to FRP, could you please give some more comments on "Your types are all weird and hard to work with", design types do matters, and I just can not figure out the key difference between types in your answer and question.

Comment: More precisely, there's two interfaces (with no implementation), and three other referenced types. To test a compiled solution against those, I would have to mock up five referenced types. The idea behind [mcve] is to put in front of potential answerers the least amount of data needed to comprehend the problem.

Comment: As for design, It seems your passing commands by ID, to be looked up in some sort of hash table. I would prefer to pass the commands themselves. it may be fine, I don't know. I don't know the context at all.

Comment: Also, "FRP" describes something specific that is related to, but distinct from Rx.net.